# Setting Background to a StaticResource pointing to a LinearGradientBrush crashes my app, any ideas?

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

So here's what's happening, I can set the background of an object to a gradient with either putting the brush directly into `Grid.Background` <strike>or setting `Background="{StaticResource BackgroundGradient}"`</strike> (I had thought that worked, but I just tested it and it also crashes the app), but setting it through a Setter (`<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundGradient}">`) crashes the app.

Setting it through a Setter worked the first time, then I closed the app and copy/pasted the Gradient a few times and changed the name and colours to make the other gradients I needed and after that it crashed every time a Setter sets the gradient.

Here is the relevant code from the Style object:

```
<Style x:Key="MainBackground" TargetType="Panel">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundGradient}"/>
</Style>
```

Here is the corresponding gradient (generated by making the gradient in design view and using 'Convert to Resource':

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="BackgroundGradient" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
        <CompositeTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5" Rotation="-90"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
    <GradientStop Color="#9BC6C5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#BAD8D7" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The only way I can currently make it work is by removing the reference to the gradient in the Style definition, but I don't really want to have to set the Gradient on individual items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very common issue, you must to ensure that this

```
<Style x:Key="MainBackground" TargetType="Panel">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundGradient}"/>
</Style>
```

is executed after this

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="BackgroundGradient" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
        <CompositeTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5" Rotation="-90"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
    <GradientStop Color="#9BC6C5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#BAD8D7" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

If you have 2 or more files to setup this resources, Try fist to setup both styles in same file and **ensure the Brush is defined before the Panel**, then it works! so proceed to make it in individial files and watch about what file is executing first.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using defining the LinearGradientBrush in the Style element itself (with `<Setter Property="Background"><Setter.Value> . . .</Setter.Value></Setter>`) to make it work, but this solution is much more elegant as I can use the same gradient for multiple styles. I just wish that Visual Studio could tell people why such things happen.

Comment: Great! that's not really happen because of Visual Studio. when WinRT use a Resource it proceed to compile this IL code to native code,  mean from begin file to the end,so in compilation it find a resource referencing other then proceed to create a link between two objects, but if one object is not already created... BOOM! So you must be carefull and create referenced resources before. This is not only at file level but application level, App.xaml is compiled firts to native, then other files/resources.

Comment: I guess the source of my problem was that I was thinking of the Resources more like methods, so didn't think that I had to define them first. I should have thought of them as properties or variables, then i wouldn't have run into the problem.